# Set paper size for printing in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

I'm trying to print document and set paper format(A4,A3,Letter ...) programmatically (without print dialog) but i can't find property to set size(format) of document to print.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What Frameworks, methods, classes, and so on are you using? Any third party libraries? HOW are you trying to print? Add code, add what you've done!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Tnx for reply, i'm using NSPrinterInfo ,NSInvocation , NSPrintOperation... and i'm printing that's all working fine but now there is a need to set page format (a4,a3...) manually from code not from dialog and issue is i cannot find where to set it.

Comment: same here, can't find a way to set paper size, iOS documentation is totally shit.

Comment: What's the problem? https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsprintinfo/1534030-papersize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation of `NSPrintInfo`, it has a property called `paperSize`, which should be more than suitable for you.

[NSPrintInfo paperSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintInfo_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPrintInfo/paperSize)

**EDIT**

An example for DIN A4 paper size:

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[printInfo setPaperSize:NSMakeSize(595, 842)];
```

Comment: Just follow the link. https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsprintinfo/1534030-papersize

Comment: Please note this is a macOS question. `UIPrintInfo` does not have this property and does not belong in the context of this thread.

Comment: And because you are too lazy and then downvoted my answer I did the research for you: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiprintpaper

Comment: Please read the *Overview* carefully. Twice. It will guide you in the right direction and give you a few options. You will need to do further research here, I won't write production code for you ;)

Comment: the question is about objective c, already declare the printinfo, 

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
and no papersize, or rect that available.

also try from printinteractioncontroller its readonly : 
printInteractionController.printPaper -> UIPrintPaper

with printpagerenderer, also readonly : 
printInteractionController.printPageRenderer.printableRect;
printInteractionController.printPageRenderer.paperRect;

any idea ?.

Comment: Yep, ObjC. The new docs show Swift by default, you can change it in the upper right region. I'll have a look later, but why would you change the paper size for a printer, that tells you which paper sizes it can print on, at all? The interactionController tells you for what paper size you will be drawinf content. Changing the paper size at this point wouldn't even make sense, would it?

Comment: And still: we are talking about macOS. You ask about iOS. It's not the same and the APIs do actually differ. This might be simply impossible to do in iOS what you want to do that way.